# jQuery - load div, and store checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, load

In one file (content.html) I have dynamically generated table (by Django). In one of seven columns I have checkbox - one checkbox for each row.

I import div, which contain this table to index.html using jQuery load() - the table refreshing every 10 seconds.
I need to store checked checkbox between refreshings because this is value for form and submit. How I can do this?

Regards!

Comment: Just create object or  array which will describe  table checkboxies state and then after refresh  update set it's value

Answer (score 0):

Well since your entire Table along with its Forms are refreshing every ten seconds, the only thing you can do here is store the form_data in [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) (if you need it to be persistent) or a state
 variable before each AJAX request that refreshes the table and in the callback for the load() function you'll have to write the code to insert those values back in.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the various solutions (I expected for ready solution from you, but not this time :)).

So, on the page where I have div to be imported (clients.html) i have following code:

```
    <div id="table_cont">
        <table>
            // Some content dynamically generated by Django //
        </table>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$('.selected_cli').on('click', function() {
  var fav, favs = [];
  $('.selected_cli').each(function() {
    fav = {id: $(this).attr('id'), value: $(this).prop('checked')};
    favs.push(fav);
  });
  localStorage.setItem("favorites", JSON.stringify(favs));
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));
  if (!favorites.length) {return};
  console.debug(favorites);

  for (var i=0; i<favorites.length; i++) {
    console.debug(favorites[i].value == 'on');
    $('#' + favorites[i].id ).prop('checked', favorites[i].value);
  }
});
</script>
```

On the index.html I have:

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
       $('document').ready(function(){
       setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
          url: "/clients/ #table_cont",
        }).done(function ( data ) {
          $("#fresh_table_cont").html(data);

        });
        }, 10000);
        });
 </script>
 <div id="fresh_table_cont"></div>
```

Is some correction necessary? From first test, I know that this work.